# SQL SubString from Special Kind of ntext column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a DB table with the column of type `ntext` filled with the values like

> A<1,?,'attrdisplay'=A<1,?,'1361147_2'='2','1361147_3'='3','1361147_4'='4','1361147_5'='5','1361147_6'='6','1361147_7'='1'>,'ClassificationInheritance'=A<1,?,'DisabledIds'=A<1,?>>,'Confidential'=0,'CreationNotification'=A<1,?,'mail'='Ärende  har skapats','recipients'=A<1,?,1414822=-1,1414823=-1,1414824=-1,1414825=-1,1414826=-1,1414827=-1,1415811=-1>>,'IsSubBinder'=1,'name'=A<1,?,'fullname'='Ärendemall5','mlNames'=A<1,?,'sv'='Ärendemall5'>,'name'='Ärendemall5','nameFormat'=':name:','ok'=true,'refnr'='SJCM-2013-00014'>,'showDocumentsFirst'=true,'WorkItem'=A<1,?,'id'=-1,'Name'=''>>

I have to extract only this value `SJCM-2013-00014` for each such row in the table.

Any idea how I can do that ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: First of all - `Ntext` is deprecated, stop using it, and where it's in use, convert it to a `nvarchar(max)`. With that **new** datatype, you have all the string functionality available - which was *not* the case with the old `Ntext` datatype...

Comment: i can understand perhaps i am not allowed to change this. is it still possible to extract this information ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you really want is to search for and extract the refnr? If you have the possibility to add CLR-functions to the server, in order to be able to use regular expressions, this is by far the easiest way:

```
CREATE TABLE #test (data ntext)
INSERT INTO #test VALUES('A<1,?,''attrdisplay''=A<1,?,''1361147_2''=''2'',''1361147_3''=''3'',''1361147_4''=''4'',''1361147_5''=''5'',''1361147_6''=''6'',''1361147_7''=''1''>,''ClassificationInheritance''=A<1,?,''DisabledIds''=A<1,?>>,''Confidential''=0,''CreationNotification''=A<1,?,''mail''=''Ärende har skapats'',''recipients''=A<1,?,1414822=-1,1414823=-1,1414824=-1,1414825=-1,1414826=-1,1414827=-1,1415811=-1>>,''IsSubBinder''=1,''name''=A<1,?,''fullname''=''Ärendemall5'',''mlNames''=A<1,?,''sv''=''Ärendemall5''>,''name''=''Ärendemall5'',''nameFormat''='':name:'',''ok''=true,''refnr''=''SJCM-2013-00014''>,''showDocumentsFirst''=true,''WorkItem''=A<1,?,''id''=-1,''Name''=''''>>')

SELECT
    *,
    [dbo].[RegexMatchGroupClr](
        CAST(data as nvarchar(max)), 
        'refnr''=''(?<refnr>[^'']+)''', 
        'refnr'
    )
FROM
    #test
```

This is done using regex in a CLR-function that looks like this in C#:

```
[SqlFunction]
public static SqlChars RegexMatchGroupClr(SqlChars input, string pattern, string groupName)
{
    if (input.IsNull) return input;

    string inputString = new string(input.Value);
    rx.Match match = rx.Regex.Match(inputString, pattern);

    if (match.Success && match.Groups[groupName].Success)
    {
        string resultString = match.Groups[groupName].Value;
        SqlChars result = new SqlChars(resultString.ToCharArray());
        return result;
    }

    return null;
}
```

If you don't have the possibility to add CLR-functions, it's still doable, but way more cumbersome:

```
CREATE TABLE #test (data ntext)
INSERT INTO #test VALUES('A<1,?,''attrdisplay''=A<1,?,''1361147_2''=''2'',''1361147_3''=''3'',''1361147_4''=''4'',''1361147_5''=''5'',''1361147_6''=''6'',''1361147_7''=''1''>,''ClassificationInheritance''=A<1,?,''DisabledIds''=A<1,?>>,''Confidential''=0,''CreationNotification''=A<1,?,''mail''=''Ärende har skapats'',''recipients''=A<1,?,1414822=-1,1414823=-1,1414824=-1,1414825=-1,1414826=-1,1414827=-1,1415811=-1>>,''IsSubBinder''=1,''name''=A<1,?,''fullname''=''Ärendemall5'',''mlNames''=A<1,?,''sv''=''Ärendemall5''>,''name''=''Ärendemall5'',''nameFormat''='':name:'',''ok''=true,''refnr''=''SJCM-2013-00014''>,''showDocumentsFirst''=true,''WorkItem''=A<1,?,''id''=-1,''Name''=''''>>')
DECLARE @SearchFor varchar(10) = 'refnr''=''';
DECLARE @EndsWith varchar(10) = '''';

WITH converted AS (
    SELECT
        CAST(data as nvarchar(max)) as data
    FROM
        #test
), startPos AS (
    SELECT
        *
        ,CHARINDEX(@SearchFor, data) + LEN(@SearchFor) as startPos
    FROM
        converted
), endPos AS (
    SELECT
        *
        ,CHARINDEX(@EndsWith, data, startPos) as endPos
    FROM
        startPos
)
SELECT
    *
    ,SUBSTRING(data, startPos, endPos - startPos) as refnr
FROM
    endPos
```

And if you can't use Common Table Expressions, it gets even more unreadable:

```
CREATE TABLE #test (data ntext)
INSERT INTO #test VALUES('A<1,?,''attrdisplay''=A<1,?,''1361147_2''=''2'',''1361147_3''=''3'',''1361147_4''=''4'',''1361147_5''=''5'',''1361147_6''=''6'',''1361147_7''=''1''>,''ClassificationInheritance''=A<1,?,''DisabledIds''=A<1,?>>,''Confidential''=0,''CreationNotification''=A<1,?,''mail''=''Ärende har skapats'',''recipients''=A<1,?,1414822=-1,1414823=-1,1414824=-1,1414825=-1,1414826=-1,1414827=-1,1415811=-1>>,''IsSubBinder''=1,''name''=A<1,?,''fullname''=''Ärendemall5'',''mlNames''=A<1,?,''sv''=''Ärendemall5''>,''name''=''Ärendemall5'',''nameFormat''='':name:'',''ok''=true,''refnr''=''SJCM-2013-00014''>,''showDocumentsFirst''=true,''WorkItem''=A<1,?,''id''=-1,''Name''=''''>>')
DECLARE @SearchFor varchar(10) = 'refnr''=''';
DECLARE @EndsWith varchar(10) = '''';

SELECT
    *
    ,SUBSTRING(data, (CHARINDEX(@SearchFor, data) + LEN(@SearchFor)), (CHARINDEX(@EndsWith, data, (CHARINDEX(@SearchFor, data) + LEN(@SearchFor)))) - (CHARINDEX(@SearchFor, data) + LEN(@SearchFor))) as refnr
FROM
    #test
```